# wordpress PHP with Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Im looking to return user data back as a string through ajax with wordpress

Iv got the basic concept down

**PHP**

> this is placed in my functions.php
>
> ```js
> add_action('template_redirect', 'edit_user_concept');
> function edit_user_concept(){
>       $id = $_POST['getbyID'];
>       $user_info = get_userdata($id);
>       echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
>       echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
>       echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
> }
> ```

**Jquery/JS**

```js
    $.ajax({
         url: "http://www.example.com/",
         method: "POST",
         data: {
             getbyID: "23",
         },
         success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
             //example script logic here
         }
    })
```

the console log result is correct how ever its also logging lots of html elements that are not included in this.
Such as

im not exactly sure why.

here is a small example to large to post in its full

```html
Username: someusername
User roles: subscriber
User ID: 23
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<div id="loadtheme" class="loadtheme"></div>
<head>

etc etc etc....
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You are echoing multiple times. My suggestion would be to store all the result in a single array and then echo like this : `echo json_encode($results);`

Comment: u want to load response in `loadtheme` ?

Comment: Can you try to put "die();" after you print user info? And yes, format your data before sending to client.

Comment: no i just want to load the responses like
username
user role
and user id

Comment: try with json_encode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing the html without stopping it anywhere, you can use json response here, for `json`, first of all you need to use `dataType: "json"` in your `ajax` request as:

```
 url: "http://www.example.com/",
 method: "POST",
 dataType: "json" // need to use datatype here.
 data: {
     getbyID: "23",
 }
```

**Now,** you need to store data in an `array` in your `PHP` as:

```
$result = array();
$result['Username'] = $user_info->user_login;
$result['User_roles'] = implode(', ', $user_info->roles);
$result['User_id'] = $user_info->ID;
```

**Now,** you can use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

You can print `json` result as like:

```
console.log(response.Username); // will print username
console.log(response.User_roles); // will print user roles
console.log(response.User_id); // will print user id
```

**Complete Example:**

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://www.example.com/",
     method: "POST",
     dataType: "json" // json data type
     data: {
         getbyID: "23",
     },
     success: function(response){
         console.log(response.Username);
         console.log(response.User_roles);
         console.log(response.User_id);
         //example script logic here
     }
 });
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
function edit_user_concept(){
  $id = $_POST['getbyID'];
  $user_info = get_userdata($id);
  $result = array();
  $result['Username'] = $user_info->user_login;
  $result['User_roles'] = implode(', ', $user_info->roles);
  $result['User_id'] = $user_info->ID;
  echo json_encode($result); // will return json response
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try exit or return after echo.I dont know the complete problem but hope this helps

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'edit_user_concept');
    function edit_user_concept(){
          $id = $_POST['getbyID'];
          $user_info = get_userdata($id);
          echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n".'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n".'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
          exit;
    }
```